# My disabled configurable products are showing in the product view?

Tags: magento

I've configurable product (for color) and some of them are "disabled" but they're still showing in the  option, any ideas?

---

I obviously flushed all caches & reindexed all the available indexers.

By the way it is working correclty locally but not on remote.

If I set a simple product (part of a configurable one) as disabled, it is correclty hidden from the  but it doesn't work on my live site.

Comment: I don't think I'm on the wrong site, it is actually a programming related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your flat product index. If you have enabled using the flat catalog product, you may want to reindex this.

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion, I edited my answer, and I obviously tried that...

Comment: When you click on the link in the category, does the product page load, or does it give you a 404?